# datatable emptymessage does not automatically colspan to total no. of columns when datatable has no rows

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I am using Primefaces 5.2 over Weblogic 11g/Java 1.6/Jsf 2.1.
I have a datatable whose certain rows are conditionally NOT rendered. 
My problem is that when the datatable has NO rows to display, the emptyMessage is spanned to only the first column and not to all the columns. Below is my datatable sample.

```
<p:dataTable var="sale" >
    <f:facet name="header">
        Sales/Profits of Manufacturers
    </f:facet>

    <p:columnGroup type="header">
        <p:row>
            <p:column rowspan="3" headerText="Manufacturer" />
            <p:column colspan="4" headerText="Sale Rate" />
        </p:row>
        <p:row>
            <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Sales" />
            <p:column colspan="2" headerText="Profit" />
        </p:row>
        <p:row>
            <p:column headerText="Last Year" />
            <p:column headerText="This Year" />
            <p:column headerText="Last Year" />
            <p:column headerText="This Year" />
        </p:row>
    </p:columnGroup>

    <p:column rendered="false">
        <h:outputText value="s" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column rendered="false">
        <h:outputText value="s" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column rendered="false">
        <h:outputText value="s" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column rendered="false">
        <h:outputText value="s">

        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column rendered="false">
        <h:outputText value="s">

        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Tried a newer release?

Comment: sorry. i am using pf5.2 and not pf5.1

Comment: See the answer? Very easy to find... just check issuelists, blogs etc... (all can be done via google to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a known [issue](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/387).

It is fixed in 5.2.6 and 5.1.20. For most of the people it should be available in 5.3 version.